# Website does not automatically redirect to adfs log in

Tags: asp.net, adfs

I am trying to set up a company website to use an adfs log in system, using the instructions found on https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-implement-sso-aspnet-mvc-application-adfs-tuomas-kesti, but my site does not redirect to the adfs page, and instead loads the home page of the site as if nothing happened. Looking at the network page in inspect element shows that the site never calls or redirects to the adfs page.

In my web.config file, the realm and reply values are set up to the main site, with the issuer value being the adfs site and follows the same format of "https://sts.domain.com/adfs/ls/". The adfs site is up and running with and the thumbprint from its certificate is added in the  tag. passiveRedirectEnabled is set to true in the  tag.

Im not sure what the problem is, and looking it up online doesn't find me any results. If anyone has an idea on why my site isn't autocratically redirecting, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that the code in your tutorial doesn't redirect automatically when no JWT is available. I.e. the last code sample should contain an 'else' that responds with a redirect to the ADFS login page.

Have a look at these samples for Azure AD:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples

I found them very helpful and they can (mostly) be used with a standalone ADFS as well. Most of all, they cover all sorts of solution architectures and framework versions.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I thought the <federationConfiguration> section in web.config is what is needed for the website to redirect. What else is needed?

Comment: No, the federationConfiguration just specifies where the ADFS sever is and which ClientID the app has there. I also believe the example in your linkedin post uses direct Windows authentication, not OAuth2 (JWT) ..? I.e. you wouldn't be redirected to a login page, the app assumes the user is already logged in. (This only works with IE/Edge)